# Connecting to Asterisk AMI via shell script - Permission Denied

Tags: shell, asterisk, asteriskami

I am trying to create a shell script to listen for events from the Asterisk AMI, but when I attempt to connect, I get:

```
Response: Error
Message: Permission denied
```

Here is the relevant code from my script:

```
set username "username"
set secret "secret"
set host "127.0.0.1"
set port "5038"

spawn telnet $host $port

expect "Manager/1.3" {
    send_user "Connected.\n"
    send "Action: Login \nUsername: ${username}\nSecret: ${secret}\n\n"
}
```

The thing is, if I log in manually to that host and port using the exact same username and password, it works just fine.

In case it helps here is the relevant code from manager.conf

```
[general]
enabled = yes
bindaddr = 127.0.0.1
port = 5038

[username]
secret=secret
read=call
write=all
```

The output to CLI confirms that it's trying to connect from 127.0.0.1

I feel like I must be missing something obvious but can't figure out what it is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

And staring at the code long enough has produced the answer.  I left an extra space after `Action: Login` before sending that `/n`  the system took offense.  I removed the space and the program logs in perfectly.